# Changing the color of an svg image using CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following svg image in my html file:

```
<img class="svg" src="my-image-link.svg">
```

Now, I am trying to change the color using this css code:

```
.svg path {
    fill: black;
}
```

However, nothing changes. What is the correct way to change the color of an svg image's path using css? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to use an inline SVG, where the path element is inside the HTML, as opposed to linking to an external SVG.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/fznuckb0/1/

```
.path-name {
    fill: tomato;
    fill-rule: evenodd;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are using the svg in a image tag, it is not possible to change anything within the SVG...

to do that, you have to include the whole SVG inline... look for example here: [link](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-7)